# 3D normal/look-at vector from Euler angles

Tags: javascript, 3d

I'm working on a JavaScript/Canvas 3D FPS-like engine and desperately need a normal vector (or look-at vector if you will) for near and far plane clipping. I have the x and y axis rotation angles and am able to do it easily with only one of them at the time, but I just can't figure out how to get both of them...

The idea is to use this vector it to calculate a point in front of the camera, the near and far clipping planes must also be definable by constants so the vector has to be normalized, I hoped that with only the angles it would be possible to get this vector length to 1 without normalizing, but that's not the problem.

I don't have any roll (rotation around z axis) so it's that much easier.

My math looks like this:

```
zNear = 200; // near plane at an arbitrary 200 "points" away from camera position

// normal calculated with only y rotation angle (vertical axis)
normal = {
    x: Math.sin(rotation.y),
    y: 0,
    z: Math.cos(rotation.y)};
```

Then clip a point in 3D space by testing the vector from the plane to it by means of a dot product.

```
nearPlane = {
    x: position.x+normal.x*zNear,
    y: position.y+normal.y*zNear,
    z: position.z+normal.z*zNear};

// test a point at x, y, z against the near clipping plane
if(
    (nearPlane.x-x)*normal.x+
    (nearPlane.y-y)*normal.y+
    (nearPlane.z-z)*normal.z < 0
)
{
    return;
}

// then project the 3D point to screen
```

When a point is behind the player its projection coordinates are reversed (x=-x, y=-y) so nothing makes sense any more, that's why I'm trying to remove them.

[image]

I want that green arrow there, but in 3D.

Comment: If you give me 3 points A,B,C making two vectors (AB and BC), I can get you a normal using the cross product...  will that help?

Comment: @dustmachine: no, I need the look-at vector from the Euler x and y rotation angles, I don't have any other data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some intensive brain processing I figured out that

1. My original look-at vector was (0, 0, 1)
2. The z-rotation angle (roll) was always 0
3. There was no reason for the rotation matrix found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) not to work

By applying the full rotation matrix on the (0, 0, 1) vector and taking in account that rz = 0 the solution I got was:

```
normal = {
    x: Math.cos(camera.rotation.x)*Math.sin(camera.rotation.y),
    y: -Math.sin(camera.rotation.x),
    z: Math.cos(camera.rotation.y)*Math.cos(camera.rotation.x)};
```

And now everything works perfectly. The error was using only the x and y rotation matrices without taking in account rz = 0 for all angles which changed the matrix a little.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same exact thing, only my roll is never 0. Any idea on where I could find the generalized version of the formulas you wrote on this answer? I would, like you, convert euler angles of an object into normal coordinates. Thank you.